# Ubuntu 12.04 + Intel GPU: random freezes

Tags: 12.04, freeze, intel, gpu, apport

I have a ThinkPad T420 with Intel Graphics, and an external monitor through DisplayPort. I was running 12.10 with no problems, but 2 days ago, after an update, my system started to crash with no reason.

Well, I was already planning to come back to 12.04 LTS, so I did it a few hours ago. After a clean install and updates, I got the same random crashes.

This [guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270352/ubuntu-12-10-intel-gpu-compiz-crashes?rq=1) seems to have the same problem I'm facing. Is there anything I can do to help fixing this issue?

Comment: I have the same thing. Seems to be a problem with Firefox (head over to their forums for way more complaints) and they've narrowed it down to the add-block add on. I've uninstalled ABPlus and so far there's been no crash. Still testing though - I only did this 30 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

2D Acceleration on Intel graphics has been a little unstable lately. Tough to duplicate but it seems to have made its way upstream -- I was having the same problems on Edgers a few weeks ago that you guys are now having on stable, and my problems have cleared up meanwhile.

The solution for now (if you don't want to switch to an unstable branch in search of stability) is not to use 2D acceleration in any application (Skype and VLC are also prominent ones, but I believe both allow you to shut it off). It'll cause slightly higher CPU usage but no other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my dell L502x running 12.10, however I was not using an external monitor. I similarly did a clean install of 12.04 with the same result. I have found that the crashes on my system seem to be caused by Firefox, and after switching to Chromium I have not experienced any more crashes or apport messages.